# Does LaTeX takes into account the DPI of an image ? Or just the pixels?

Tags: graphics

Two images with same resolution (nb of pixels width and height) but with a ration of 2:1 in DPI one will display two times bigger than the other ?

Comment: 'None of the above': it's the _size_ that's important. Can you tell us a bit more about your images: not all programs correctly set the physical size for _e.g._ `.png` files.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2):

The graphics package does indeed use the natural size of images (eps and pdf files do not have a pixel size). You can manually override the size to either a set size or to a given scale. Using the DPI stored in the png obviously requires the DPI to be correctly set on the image.